# Gets "error TS1005: ';' expected"

Tags: angular

I'm playing with Angular JS's tutorial file and trying to add third play library from my work. I downloaded the library and put it inside node-modules directory. When run this tutorial, I get TS1005 (missing semicolon error) on the init function call. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error since the line already has semicolon. Anyone care to shed light on my mistake?

```
import { Component }          from '@angular/core';

export class RE {
  enabled: string;
}

export class Configuration {
  pToken: string;
  sToken: string;
  r: RE;
  e: RE;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',

  template: `
   <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/da/b-cl/ua.js">
   <h1>{{title}}</h1>
   <nav>
   <a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a>
   <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
   </nav>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
`,
  styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
title = 'Tour of Heroes';

rVar: RE = {
  enabled: "true",
  url: "https://...."
};  

eVar: RE = {
  enabled: "true",
  url: ""
};  

config: Configuration = {
 pToken: "aa",
 sToken: "a",
 r: this.rVar,
 e: this.eVar

};

init(config);

}
```

Comment: What is `init(config);` supposed to do? There is no `init` method or function to call.

Comment: init is method form the third party library. I just put a script tag referring to that library in the template. I'm sure that's probably not the right way to import. How do I do that?

Comment: Script tags in templates are silently removed. You should use `require()` or similar to include scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have

```
init(config);
```

outside a method or the constructor.

Only property and method declarations are allowed outside methods or the constructor.

This might do what you want

```
  export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';

    rVar: RE = {
      enabled: "true",
      url: "https://...."
    };  

    eVar: RE = {
      enabled: "true",
      url: ""
    };  

    config: Configuration = {
     pToken: "aa",
     sToken: "a",
     r: this.rVar,
     e: this.eVar

    };

    init(config:config) {
      // do some initialization here
    }

    constructor() {
      this.init(config);
    }
  }
```